# How i can safe the curl result in a bash variable

Tags: bash, curl

When i run the command 
`curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST https://xxx.xxxx.de/xx/xx.php 2>/dev/null` on the normal command line i get the requested result `{"success":false,"cause":"Token needed"}`.

I need this result on a bash script but when i try to run it

```
curl = "$(curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST https://xxx.xxxx.de/xx/xx.php 2>/dev/null)"
echo $curl
```

I don't recieve the requested result i recieve this

```
[1/2]: "success":false --> <stdout>
--_curl_--"success":false
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

[2/2]: "cause":"Token needed" --> <stdout>
--_curl_--"cause":"Token needed"
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

How i can use the correct result in my bash script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is not a variable assignment, it tries to executes `curl` with arguments `=` and the output of the command substitution. Remove the space characters before and after `=` and you may omit the quotes around the command substitution (this is one of the few occasions where quotes are not needed).

```
curl=$(curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST https://xxx.xxxx.de/xx/xx.php 2>/dev/null)
echo "$curl"
```